# Swi Prolog Editor only shows false, not true

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, unification

Assume my knowledge base contains one fact:
fact(fact1).

If I know submit a query fact(fact1).

```
39 ?- fact(fact1).

40 ?-
```

it says nothing, which is the equivalent to true. B/c if it's wrong, Prolog responds with false:

```
38 ?- fact(foobar).
false.
```

So how can I change it so I get a true.  ?

Comment: Try `fact(X).` first!

Comment: Yeah then I get all possible unifications, I do not want that. I just want to get a true.   like the false. statement

Comment: with `a(a).` in my program, and querying `a(a).`, I get `true.`. What version do you use?

Comment: SWI-Prolog-Editor 4.26, 26.04.2015
SynEdit 2.05

Comment: @InDaPond: That you do not get a `true` for your first query is what struck me.

Comment: Yes, this is what my question is about. The nothing there is the equivalent to true, but as you can see for yourself, it is very confusing to just not get a response at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SWI Prolog Editor (at least on some versions), by default, sets the following environmental flag:

```
set_prolog_flag(prompt_alternatives_on, groundness).
```

To display **true** you can change it like this:

```
set_prolog_flag(prompt_alternatives_on, determinism).
```

This has the side effect of requiring the user to press  after each **true** to return to the interactive prompt though... (Not sure if there is some better way to achieve this.)